# Отправка сообщений из google таблицы в telegram

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

есть скрипт для отправки в telegram сообщений на основании заполненой Gooogle формы. Вопрос какие строки добавить в скрипт чтобы в сообщении отправки была ссылка на таблицу куда сваливаються ответы с формы? Спасибо

```
const token = 'токен бота';

function getSheetById(id) { 
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
    function (s) { return s.getSheetId() === id; }
  )[0];
}
const Order = getSheetById(id листа);
const Workers = getSheetById(id листа);

function sendTelegram() {
  let lastRow = Order.getLastRow();
  let workers = Workers.getRange(2, 1, Workers.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let nameManager = Order.getRange(lastRow,5).getValue();
  let flatManagers = workers.flat();
  let rowManager = flatManagers.indexOf(nameManager) + 2;
  let chatId = Workers.getRange(rowManager, 2).getValue();
  let data = Order.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 6).getDisplayValues()[0];
  let name = let name = ss.getName();
 
let text = 
$ {name}
${data[1]}
${data[2]}
  
  sendText(chatId, text)
}
 
function sendText(chatId, text) {
  let data = {
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id: String(chatId),
    text: text,
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
  };
  let options = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: data
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', options)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего надо что-то такое `<a href="${url}">${name}</a>`

```js
const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();

const text = `
<a href="${url}">${name}</a>
${data[1]}
${data[2]}
`;

sendText(chatId, text) {
```

Answer (score 0):

У объекта **Spreadsheet** есть метод **getUrl**

Подробнее [в документации](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getUrl())

В вашем же случае будет как-то так

```
let url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();
```

В переменной **url** будет ссылка. А дальше уже добавляйте ее куда вам надо.

Comment: Спасибо, а так что бы ссылка не выглядела как ссылка а в виде названия файла таблицы, в моем коде переменная let (name) берет название файла таблицы для последующей вставки в телеграм